# Why there is not a copy when return constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() { OutputDebugStringA("Construct\n"); };
    ~Test() { OutputDebugStringA("Destruct\n"); };
    Test(const Test& other) { OutputDebugStringA("Copy Construct\n"); }
    Test& operator = (const Test& other) {
        OutputDebugStringA("Copy Construct\n");
        return *this;
    }
    Test GetNewTest() const {
        OutputDebugStringA("GetNewTest\n");
        return Test(); 
    }
};

int main() {
    Test test;
    Test new_test = test.GetNewTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
Construct
GetNewTest
Construct
Destruct
Destruct
```

So I think `return Test();` do not create a new `Test` and **copy** to the return value. Is it defined in C++ standard or it's compiler optimizations behavior ? I'm using VS2015.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @JonathanPotter Oh thanks !